# ColdFusion Builder throwing an error about my open project

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, adobe, coldfusionbuilder

I am trying to open Adobe ColdFusion Builder, and it is throwing the following error:

```
"open project has encountered a problem"

Problems occurred opening the selected resources.
The project description file (.project) for 'dev - work' is missing.
This file contains important information about the project.
The project will not function properly until this file is restored.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about ovbious steps? It looks like you accidentally deleted the Eclipse project configuration file.

Check if ''.project'' file exists in project directory. If it is missing, re-creating the project and copying the source files from the old is the way to fix it.

Also you can try to create project with same name and copy the ''.project'' file to the old one. Bu you'll need to remove this invalid project first (without deleting the source files) and import it later, because Eclipse (FBuilder) wont allow you to have two projects with same name in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using developing on windows 7 platform, go to you workspace folder(not where you project is located) right click go to restore select an earlier version. it worked for me